# Differences between 'Add web site/solution to source control...'

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I have opened a website website hosted on my workstation in Visual Studio 2008 and saved it as solution. I now want to add this to source contol and I am being given the option to either 'Add solution to source control...' or 'Add web site to source control...'.

This solution needs to be accessed, worked on and run locally by several other developers so I was wondering what the key differences are between each option and which would be the best to choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is a project aggregator.

- If you have several projects on your solution and you want your colleagues to work with all the same way you do, them you must add the solution.
- If you have several projects on your solution and you do **NOT** want your colleagues to work with all the same way you do, them you must **NOT** add the solution.
- If you only have one project it is really the same, but I would add the solution so if at a later time someone adds a project to it, I would have immediate access to it.